# Replace " " to ' ' if there no ' ' inside already

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with different words like

```
let str = `'code' AND js AND "test" OR "'unit'" AND "work" AND "'apple'" `;
```

If between `"` and `"`, is a `''` leave it as it is (like `"'unit'"` and `"'apple'"`).

If it's simple `"word"` - replace to `'word'` (like `"test"` and `"work"`)

So output for my string should be:

```
replacedStr = ` 'code' AND js AND 'test' OR "'unit'" AND 'work' AND "'apple'" `;
```

I've tried to make it by `.replace(/"/g, "'")` but it works for all double-ticks.

I think it needed to be done by RegEx but I'm new to it.
Maybe someone can help me with it. Would be really grateful!

Comment: please remember thet when you post a regex question you MUST specify what language are you using in the TAGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably overthinking this by a mile, but if there are always pairs of double quotes maybe you could try:

```
(?=(?:"[^"]*?"[^"]*)+$)"([^"']*?)"
```

And replace by `'$1'`. See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/whizGo/1).

The idea here is to assert positions that are always followed by pairs of double quotes.

- `(?=` - Open positive lookahead:

  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

    - `"[^"]*?"[^"]*` - Match a double quote, 0+ (lazy) characters other than double quote up to the next double quote. Followed by 0+ characters other than double quote.
    - `)+$)` - Close non-capture group and match 1+ times up to end string anchor to assure there are always pair(s) of double quotes ahead. Close lookahead.
- `"` - An opening double quote.
- `([^"']*?)` - A capture group to grab everything between the two double quotes.
- `"` - A closing double quote.

Comment: @MarkMark, JS is not my forte, but I do like that the link I included has a code generator on the left which when you click does give you a sample of some valid JS coding.

Comment: Yeah, I've already found that tab, thank's a lot for your help! You're save my life today!)